# money transfer to US for medical treatment

Tags: money-transfer, healthcare

I am going to the US for medical treatment for which I need to pay INR 25 lakhs to a hospital.

1. What is the procedure to transfer the money?
2. What is the limit per transfer?
3. Is the transfer taxable?

Answer (score 2):

You should contact the hospital and ask them how they would like to be paid. They can probably accept an international wire transfer which would make a lot of sense in this case. I know of no limits to those transactions. If your payment is made directly to the hospital, I can't think of any reason it would be taxed any differently than the payment of any other service.

Comment: India has restrictions on transfers out of the country.  These are probably the limits and potential taxes the OP is asking about; not the US hospital accepting payment.